# Is it appropriate to ask for a raise after reducing working hours?

Tags: raise

I'm a web developer in a *very* small company. when I started out I intentionally asked for a below-market salary (and got it) with a promise for a raise once I'm settled in and everything seems to be working.
Since I've started with such a low salary I can't possibly imagine that simply asking for a raise will do me much good, which is why I'm thinking of asking for a rather big raise (~25% which will put me on average-market salary) and compromising for a bit less.
I know that I deserve such a raise and that I'm essential enough that I could realistically ask for it but the problem is that due to other obligations I've just reduced my working hours.

I guess the main question is whether asking for a raise at this time really appropriate (Assuming I most likely will get it)

Comment: did you reduce your hours for the same pay per week (or month) or for the same pay per hour? If the former, you've already had a raise. If the latter, you risk them thinking you didn't think the "reducing hours" thing through even if that's not your motivation.

Comment: I get paid per hour and my schedule is very flexible since I'm also a student - which is why I had to reduce the amount of hours I've been working and they are fully aware of that. as I said I'm quite essential to the company which means that for them "every hour counts", and "the more the better".

Comment: I can always ask and will probably get the raise. My question is more one of etiquette than "how to maximize my chances". I guess a rephrasing could be "Is it really bad manners to ask for a huge raise right after changing my work hours?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you ask for a raise, you should be able to justify your worth. Your comments sound like you can do that. Limiting your hours is just another factor. The company's willingness to limit your hours took your productivity into consideration. Although you just made this request and are thankful they gave it to you, your salary increase (which was agreed on) has not been addressed.

It's important that you recognize what they've done for you in the recent request. It is usually more difficult to get a raise after just getting some compensation in another form.

Can you realistically get another job at the market rate but with your reduced hours? I'm not so sure.

I'm not sure what you mean by politely asking. Have you received feedback from people that you come across as rude in your requests? If there is an issue with timing, maybe you need to wait.